# Passing an array to a function

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP code in sample.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>
           PHP Test
       </title>
       <?php
          include "sample1.php";
       ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php     
            echo "<br> ";       
            echo arrayAdder([1,2,3,4]);
            echo "<br> ";
        ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my function located in sample1.php

```
function arrayAdder($array){
    $total = count($array);
    return $total;
}
```

I tried to run sample.php in my browser, but an error occurs saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 13
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Your PHP version is most likely below the required version to use the [shorthand PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). `PHP 5.4` is the version for reference (required).

Comment: just maybe shorthand array is not supported, try `array(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `array shorthand syntax` is supported by `PHP >= 5.4` ([New features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)). your version might not support the syntax. check the version. and for now try this -

```
    <?php     
        echo "<br> ";       
        echo arrayAdder(array(1,2,3,4));
        echo "<br> ";
    ?>
```

Comment: may i know the reason?

Comment: "try this" isn't helpful at all. He needs to know *why*, not just be spoon-fed code without having any idea what the problem is. The two comments below the question are much more helpful than this answer.

Comment: its bcoz the shorthand syntax of array supported by php >= 5.4. she might be using lesser..

Comment: the simple point is, (no need to be eloquent), just state the reason, and then back it up with the correct answer, clearly the OP doesn't know why then just add an explanation, the OP said `Whats wrong with my code?`

Answer (score 2):

Short array syntax was added to PHP in version 5.4. You'll need to make sure you're running a version of PHP >= 5.4.

You can check by creating a script with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` as its contents, or running `php -v` from the command line.

If you're not able to update your PHP to 5.4 or later, you can always switch back to the traditional style of defining arrays, `array(1, 2 ,3 ,4)`.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php